# How to read CSV file content from box-java-sdk in chunks

Tags: box-api, box

Hi i am using [box][1]

[1]: https://www.box.com/ to store my csv file. Size of file is 2GB. Now i want to process each record of file and do some operation based on file content.

what i did:

```
public class BoxConnector {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BoxAPIConnection api = new BoxAPIConnection("My access token");

    BoxFolder rootFolder = BoxFolder.getRootFolder(api);
    for (BoxItem.Info itemInfo : rootFolder) {
        System.out.format("[%s] %s\n", itemInfo.getID(), itemInfo.getName());
        BoxFile file = new BoxFile(api, itemInfo.getID());
        BoxFile.Info info = file.getInfo();
        try {
            System.out.println(info.getSize());

            File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("file", "temp");
            FileOutputStream fsTmpStrem = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
            long blockSize = 1000;
            long roundChunks = info.getSize() / blockSize;
            long startByteRange = 0;
            long endByteRange = blockSize;
            for (long start = 0; start < roundChunks; start++) {

                file.downloadRange(fsTmpStrem, startByteRange, endByteRange);
                processFile(tmpFile);
                startByteRange = endByteRange;
                endByteRange = endByteRange + blockSize;
            }
            //last download block
            file.downloadRange(fsTmpStrem, blockSize * roundChunks, info.getSize());
            processFile(tmpFile);

        } finally {

        }
    }
}

private static void processFile(File tmpFile) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(tmpFile)));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println("Process line record");
    }
    br.close();
    //after each process lets delete the temp file
    tmpFile.delete();

}
```

}

with this i am able to get the file name which i have uploaded to box.com. Now i want to read each record and process.
However i need an API which allows me file chunk access .

with this files are getting downloaded as per chunk defined by start and end byte range flag.however due to chunk download i am getting few records broken . Meaning i am not getting complete line say below is my record

```
16F11C78-D004-4600-8D28-445C087D2A7D 
31C99F3D-D4C7-418A-9ACC-D9A382BCD53A 
30C1AA92-B5B7-4ABF-A631-A8C150D90C4F
D9FC1DBF-B309-4BB1-8955-D9F48F643E97
```

i am getting

```
    16F11C78-D004-4600-8D28-445C087D2A7D 
    31C99F3D-D4C7-418A-9ACC-D9A382BCD53A 
    30C1AA92-B5B7-4ABF-A631-A8C150D90C4F
    D9FC1DBF-
```

`i.e. B309-4BB1-8955-D9F48F643E97` part from last line is missing. 
How should i manage this with download API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the Box API. You can only download an entire file.

Comment: Yes i can download to outputstream.  i tried range download as per code added above. Here due to range definition for start and end bytes . few records are getting downloaded partially. how can we overcome this. Thanks